# How to resolve ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or is used out of proper order in SAS without restarting?

Tags: sql, error-handling, sas

In SAS, when using PROC SQL, I receive the error message

> ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or is used out of proper order

relatively frequently due to missing out a semi colon in the PROC SQL statement. However, even if I fix the code, these errors are not resolved unless I quit the SAS application and restart it and rerun the fixed code.

Does anyone know of a way to resolve these errors that doesn't require having to restart SAS for the fix to work?

Comment: Please edit your question to share an example of code that causes the error shown so that we can try it for ourselves and test any potential solution before posting an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to recover by submitting an appropriate [magic string](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/08/19/errors-that-cause-sas-to-freeze.html), e.g.

```
*;*';*";*/;quit;
```

Comment: user667489 can you add more details to this, how to use that magic string, and what it does? It didn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @ArpanSaini The idea is to close off any unfinished lines of code, quoted strings, comments, procs (and macros, if you include a `%mend`) that SAS is still waiting for you to submit before it can move on to running the next part of your code. You may well get some further errors after submitting the magic string but at least you have a chance of regaining control of your SAS session. Read the linked blog post for full details.

Answer (score 0):

i was using the format statement before the date was formated using input statement, once i corrected the order of the statement, resolved my issue.

```
   /* format lstLirAprvDt date10.; */
   lstLirAprvDt=input(lstLirAprvDt_dt, yymmdd10.);
   format lstLirAprvDt date10.;
```

Comment: This does not look like an answer to this question. But note that DATE10 format makes no sense. You need a width of 9 to display four digit years. Or you could use a width of 11 to include hyphens around the month.  But a width of 10 characters make no sense for the DATE format.   But just adding the format statement before the assignment statement would not make any difference.

Comment: Tom, I have mentioned one of the scenarios that caused exactly the same error. The error mentioned can be due to various reasons. Due to this error, i struggled for 2 hours and later realized the order of statements was the problem, after I fixed that it got resolved. yymmdd10. gives the format DDMONYYYY i.e 12Dec2022. There was no issue with the date format which was working fine. I have added the answer to help the community with similar errors and thank you for adding more info

Comment: Moving the format statement would make no difference in the code snippet you posted.  Most likely when you moved the format statement you accidentally fixed the actual cause.